# $\int \sec x \sqrt{\tan x} \, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

Can this be solved in terms of elementary functions? If not, what is the *approach*?

$\int \sec x \sqrt{\tan x} \,\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Please see here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sec+x+(tan+x)%5E(0.5)

Comment: Why care about this?

Comment: this integral leads to an elliptic function

Comment: No, it cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions. Solving it gives elliptic integrals of the first and second kind.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt{\tan x}=t$.

Hence, $\frac{dx}{\cos^2x}=2tdt$, which gives $dx=\frac{2tdt}{1+t^4}$.

Hence, we need to calculate the following $\int\frac{2t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}dt$